# Stop unknown devices trying to connect to Apple TV

Tags: security, bluetooth, appletv

I have a 4th generation Apple TV and I live in an apartment block, so I have very nearby neighbours.

While I was watching a video, it was interrupted by the 4 digit confirmation screen of a new connection (Ryan's iPhone) flashing up.

I don't know Ryan, and I don't appreciate him interrupting my viewing.

I've checked my Wi-Fi router's status and it indicates that Ryan's iPhone is not connected to my WLAN. I presume that this was an attempt to connect via Bluetooth.

How do I prevent this from happening again and only allow connections from previously authorised devices?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can give AirPlay a password in the settings on your Apple TV. Only with this password you can connect.

1. Open Settings
2. AirPlay
3. Change 'Security' to Password
4. Turn off 'Require Device Verification'

Answer (score 3):

In tvOS 13 there is a new option which should make this easier:

Settings > Airplay and Homekit > Allow Access

Change "Also Allow Nearby to Airplay" to Off

Answer (score 0):

First, you'll want to add a WPA password to your network, if you don't have one already. This will prevent nearly all unwanted connections to your Apple TV. 
Next, you should go into the AirPlay settings on your Apple TV, and set a static password. This means that, rather than having a one time password appear, any device that you want to connect just has to enter the password that you set. No pop-ups, no nothing.